# How many ways are there to separate n numbers into 3 groups

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I saw the following answer https://doubleroot.in/lessons/permutations-combinations/division-into-groups-1/ and it was almost the answer.

But I need to give an answer to the following exact question:

How many ways are there to separate the group {1, 2,...,n} into three groups when:

- The order of the numbers in groups and the order of the groups is not important.
- 1 or 2 of groups can be empty.

If I assume that the number of elements in each of the three groups is k1, k2 and k3 accordingly, then the number of ways to separate the n numbers into the groups is n!/(k1!k2!k3!) .

But i need the full calculation, including the count of the different k1,k2,k3 options.

Comment: The correct search term here is Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.  The final answer will be $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right\}+\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right\}+\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\3\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$.  (*Note that $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}n\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$ both simplify very easily as $1$ and $2^{n-1}-1$ respectively, but it is worth seeing them written as stirling numbers to see the overall formula for what it is*)

Answer (score 1):

Each number can be placed in one of three groups, so there are $3^n$ ways of placing all the numbers if the groups were distinct.

In $3$ of those cases all the numbers are in the same group, so we should divide them by $3$.  In all the rest there are $3!$ ways to permute the groups, so there are $$\frac 16(3^n-3)+1=\frac 16(3^n+3)$$ ways to divide the numbers into three groups.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I dont seem to understand why you have deducted 3, and why you have added one. also, it seems odd that you divide by 3!, because it is mentioned that the orders of the groups does not matter.

Comment: Dividing by 3! is precisely because the orders of the groups does not matter.